# is there timer in ios

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to create a timer for example to count 2 sec and after each second an nslog type for example 1 sec passed

any suggestion to do that

Answer (score 18, accepted):

yes there is NSTimer, use it as -

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector() userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: target:self selector:@selector(printmESSEAGE:) YOU MEAN , WHEN the printmESSEAGE will be caled , after one second or at the end of the interval , how to control the calling time of this function

Comment: NSTimer will call the specified function in selector after the time interval we pass here.

Comment: how to implement the part of firring certain function every 1 sec for 4 sec interval for example

Comment: you have to fire it for every 1 sec, and in that function manage a count that how much time that function executed and after count > 4 call [timer invalidate]; for this you also have to create NSTimer *timer in .h also.

Answer (score 4):

What you're after is [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Which, I can't not point out, even a cursory search of the framework docs would have turned up. Laziness IS one of the three [Virtues of the Programmer](http://www.hhhh.org/wiml/virtues.html), but c'mon.

Comment: @AMH - No, I mean there's lots of documentation that you might want to look at before coming here and asking big broad general questions.

Comment: @AMH - For that matter, guess what the first google result for "timer in ios" is? Google will get you answers MUCH faster than posting your google search on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can call your NSTimer like this

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(changeValue) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

changeValue function can be like

```
-(void)changeValue{
    NSLog("calling function after every two seconds");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html)s `timerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:`
method. Point that towards some object that implements a selector which prints your log entries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ios having timer which is used for periodically call method or button touchup event. we can use it like following:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(Your_target_Method)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];
NSInteger timer=0;
```

now call method every 1 sec

```
-(void)Your_target_Method{

timer=timer+1;

NSLog(@"Timer:%ld",timer);

}
```

Furthermore, visit https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html